# Tiptap Events don't work when attached to an editor that is passed down to components via props

Tags: reactjs, react-native, rich-text-editor, tiptap, lexicaljs

I've created an editor using useEditor. I want to bind [events](https://tiptap.dev/api/events)  to it, to get [active](https://tiptap.dev/api/editor#is-active) state of a specific mark and [getAttributes](https://tiptap.dev/api/editor#get-attributes) to get link hrefs to update urls of previously set links. I cannot bind those events in components where i'm receiving that editor through props.

File : Editor.jsx

```js
var editor = useEditor({
    extensions: EditorExtensions,
    onUpdate({ editor }) {
      setState({
        ...state,
        json: editor.getJSON(),
        html: editor.getHTML(),
        editorTextContent: editor.state.doc.textContent,
      });
    },
  });

// passing this editor instance to toolbar down in big component
<Toolbar editor={editor} /> // relevnat part
```

Toolbar.jsx

```js
const Toolbar = ({ editor }) => {
  return (
    <div className="">
      <Btns.UndoBtn editor={editor} />
      <Btns.RedoBtn editor={editor} />
      <Btns.VerticalDivider />
      <Btns.BoldBtn editor={editor} />
      <Btns.ItalicBtn editor={editor} />
      <Btns.UnderlineBtn editor={editor} />
      <Btns.VerticalDivider />
    </div>
```

ToolbarButtons.jsx

```js
export const BoldBtn = ({ editor }) => {
  const onClick = () => editor.chain().focus().toggleBold().run();
  return (
    <IcnBtn shortcut={"Ctrl + B"} Icon={Icons.BoldIcon} onClick={onClick} />
  );
};
```

Here in toolbar buttons, I've created different buttons that accept an editor. I use this editor to update editor state, format text etc. This `BoldBtn`  is an example where i'm using editor to make text bold, it works perfectly. The problem I have exists in all other components and every component receive an editor so they are similar.

This is the problem
BoldBtn

```js
export const BoldBtn = ({ editor }) => {
  var [boldState, setBoldState] = useState(false);
  editor.on("update", ({ editor }) => {});
  editor.on("selectionUpdate", ({ editor }) => {
    var boldIsActive = editor.isActive("bold");
    setBoldState(boldIsActive);
  });

  const onClick = () => editor.chain().focus().toggleBold().run();
  return (
    <IcnBtn isActive={boldState} shortcut={"Ctrl + B"} Icon={Icons.BoldIcon} onClick={onClick} />
  );
};
```

Editor instance inside onClick works perfectly> `editor.chain().focus().toggleBold().run()`.

These `editor.on()` events don't work and give these errors

1 `Cannot read properties of null (reading 'isActive')`

2 `TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'on')`

Somehow they are null when they are accessed inside component, and work as they should inside functions.
I might be making a very basic mistake, I'm a mobile app developer, Please suggest any solution or work around for this.
Thank you.

Comment: You'll probably get better answers if you give a [mre]. The components you're using aren't part of the standard library, without imports they could be from anywhere

Comment: Yes, they are usual reactjs components and don't come with standard library. I'm using commands inside these components to format/mark text. i want to bind events to editor in BoldBtn, similar to onUpdate in `Editor.jsx` (see above). onUpdate works, but `editor.on("update", ()=>{})` doesn't. This is what I'm trying to solve. Thank you.

Comment: From your code i assume that you just want apply some style to IcnBtn that if the text is bold then make it active or change it's css am i right? instead of this 

editor.on("selectionUpdate", ({ editor }) => {
    var boldIsActive = editor.isActive("bold");
    setBoldState(boldIsActive);
  });
 can you please try just this line once var boldIsActive = editor.isActive("bold");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use useEffect hook, pass editor as a dependency, inside useEffect you can attach events.

```js
    export const BoldBtn = ({ editor }) => {
      var [state, setState] = useState();
      useEffect(() => {
        if (!editor) {
          console.log("No Editor");
          return;
        }
        editor.on("update", ({ editor }) => {
          var boldIsActive = editor.isActive("bold");
          setState(boldIsActive);
          console.log("boldstate", state);
        });
      }, [editor]);
    
      const onClick = () => editor.chain().focus().toggleBold().run();
      return (
        <IcnBtn
          active={state}
          shortcut={"Ctrl + B"}
          Icon={Icons.BoldIcon}
          onClick={onClick}
        />
      );
    };
```